# How can I automatic size Collection View cell containing text in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewlayout, ios10, xcode8

I want to make a Collection View like the one made by Apple in this video (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/219/?time=1500) where each cell contains a word of a text in a UILabel, like in the following image.
In the video they use the new `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize`constant for `estimatedItemSize`. 
[image: Collection View with text]

What is the best way to do this in iOS 10? How can I use `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize` with Storyboard?

Comment: Sorry if I've made some mistakes with the language, I'm an Italian student

Comment: This question is primarily opinion-based, too broad, and lacks [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or any attempt to solve the problem by the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create your own subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and set the Flow Layout object of your Collection View in your Storyboard to this custom class, then write this code in your custom class:

```
override init() {
    super.init()
    estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Obviously you have to set the target of your app to iOS 10

Comment: How can you achieve the same thing in iOS 9?

Answer (score 0):

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind
 kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind,      
    withReuseIdentifier: "headerId", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    return header
}
```

May be you need this method for Header in your UICollectionView Cell's
And also to make a size of this header, method:

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layoutcollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 50)
}
```

And if you have your own header class, make sure u register it in viewDidLoad

```
    collectionView?.registerClass(HeaderCell.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "headerId")
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your answer. I've edited the question to explain better my situation @blinkmeoff

Comment: if you'd like to have a header for each cell like Apple do, you can use those methods that i showed you.

Comment: There is no header for each cell. the cells of the collection view are individual words

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    // Calculating size of string for given fontsize
    let text = someDataArray[indexPath.row]
    let font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(15) // use your font size
    let attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : font])
    let height = attributedText.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.width, CGFloat.max), options: [NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading, NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin], context: nil).height
    let size = CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width, height: height)
    return size
}
```

The function calculates cell height for the given string, font size and width. ( I used self.view.bounds.width so the cell is as wide as the screen)